# change date format from epoch to date in kibana-7.1.1

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard, kibana-4

I am working on kibana-7.1.1. I want it to be interactive. I have one field of timestamp where field type is in epoch format.

But I want to filter data in date format.

I feel that I will have to insert data in date format rather than inserting in epoch format. Is there any other way that I insert data in epoch format(because my original data file is in this format.) but still I can use filter on date format?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You possibly just need to change the mapping for this epoch field to date.

Elasticsearch is able to convert several date formats into a date mapped field just by guessing it. For special cases/date formats you're also able to specify a custom date pattern.

Please have a look on the documentation on this topic here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html

Have Fun!

Comment: It's pretty obvious: Read the dic referencrd above and cosider this document too: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Comment: Do I have to do the mapping before inserting data or after inserting data?

Comment: It does not include changing inserted data into different type of data.

Comment: Before. If you store data in a index, the mapping will be guessed by elasticsearch based in the first document.